# I want to change the page name in wordpress from capnel

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to change the page name in cpanel but when after changing the page name when i try to open it it say page not found

I tried to do it manually but still not able to get it.

Comment: Are you changing the .php file name or changing the slug of post?

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the page name in cPanel, it's possible that the old URL is still being cached by your browser. Try clearing your browser's cache and cookies and then accessing the page again.

If that doesn't work, it's possible that the change to the page name may have affected the permalinks or the .htaccess file. You can try resetting the permalinks or updating the .htaccess file to ensure that the correct redirect is in place.

If you're still unable to access the page, it could be a server-side issue and you may need to contact your web hosting provider for assistance.